# JavaScript function is not working in PhoneGap application

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have added the function in script tag and the button in body.

```
function click(){   
alert("Hello"); });
```

```html
<a onClick="click()">Book An Ambulance</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you had a syntax error, you had an extra `)` wrapped around the end of your function before the `;`.

```
function click() {
    alert("Hello");
};
```

**BTW** semicolons after a function declaration is not necessary.

Comment: First i was building my html5 app from build.phonegap but now i want noftification functionality in my app so, i had to integrate my app in cordova. After the integration, the normal html javascript stopped working.